# Function with URL call

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I get the function below to automatically take visitors to different URLs if the value they enter matches man or woman. E.g.  If it matches man, it takes them to URL A while woman takes them to URL B

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    
function isAlphabet(elem, helperMsg){
    var alphaExp = /man/;/woman/;
    if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

</script>

<form>
Letters Only: <input type='text' id='letters'/>
<input type='button' 
    onclick="isAlphabet(document.getElementById('letters'), 'Letters Only Please')"
    value='Check Field' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and questions here i did is as shown below and it works

```
function access()
{
if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='stevo' && document.getElementById('website').value=='1080' )location.href='http://www.stevsho.com'
else if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='woman')location.href='http://www.dynamicdrive.com'
else if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='cat')location.href='http://www.youtube.com'
else if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='dog')location.href='http://www.dailymotion.com'
else alert('Access denied. Try again.')



form>
<input type='text' class="clientelog" id='website' value="Website"> </input>
<input type='text' class="clientelog" id='letters' value="Code" >
</input>
<input class="checkerbttn" type='button' onclick='access()' value='show me' ></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to match the input values to URLs:

```
var urlMap = {
  'man' : 'http://some.domain/something',
  'woman' : 'http://some.domain/something/else',
  'cat' : 'http://whatever.you.want/more/here',
  'dog' : 'http://the.last.example/for/now'
};
```

Then you can just do a lookup:

```
function lookupUrl( choice ) {
  var url = urlMap[ choice ];
  if (url === undefined) throw "Improper input!";
  return url;
}
```

(Or whatever makes sense in your application.)

Your regular expression(s) in your example, by the way, should be:

```
var alphaExp = /^(?:man|woman)$/;
```

But I don't think you should do it that way anyway.

*edit* — another thing: you're calling "getElementById()" to get some element, presumably an `<input>`, but you need to make sure you check its "value" attribute:

```
var theUrl = lookupUrl(document.getElementById('letters').value);
```

Comment: I'm trying out the example you gave me but it doesn't seem to be working and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Well I just noticed something; hold on and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Pointy, here's how I placed the code, I add the declaration you gave me, yet it work and I've taken it off. Where exactly do I add it? I"ll post it so you see it.

Comment: Actually, I don't have the privilege to edit it. The question is that know what exactly you want me to edit.